# Python's Multiplication Function

Tags: python, formatting, multiplication, presentation

In python I found a multiplication solution very useful for the software I am writing.

Problem is when using the software, user is asked a question (i.e 8x2) but it prints a command-type line (i.e 14). This is not so user friendly and I would like to display it in a simpler form, like common writing form (8x2). I will post [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmdTM.png) to integrate my question.

On the right is the result screen, on the left is the code itself. If you have any more questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks very much for such quick redponses everyone, I have solved my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a dictionary with the operator descriptions:

```
op_symbols = {
    add: '+',
    mul: '*',
    sub: '-',
}
```

and instead of `str(op)`, use `op_symbols[op]`

Answer (score 1):

Add declaration of user-friendly strings:

```
opAsStr = {mul: 'x', add: '+', sub: '-'}
```

Replace `str(op)` with `opAsStr[op]` .